# Boto3 not returning all the resources that are requested

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, aws-resource-group

I am trying to import SQS queues based on resource groups and add all the visible messages available among the queues. The problem is boto3 is not returning all the queues sometimes. I know it is the problem with boto3 because I am getting correct values most of the time when I run the same code. In my case, boto3 is supposed to return 3 queues but sometimes either be or two of the queues are missing. Here is the code I have written

```
import boto3
import time
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

#clients for SQS, Cloudwatch, AutoScalingGroups, and ResourceGroups
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
asg = boto3.client('autoscaling')
rg = boto3.client('resource-groups')

#Importing SQS Queues with the tag Env:Production
response = rg.list_group_resources(Group='env_prod')
resources = response.get('Resources')
    
    
soa = 0.0 
noi = 0.0 
ABPI = 100    

def SumOfAverages(resources, soa, response, cloudwatch):
    for idents in resources:
        identifier = idents.get('Identifier')
        resourcetype = identifier.get('ResourceType')
        if resourcetype == 'AWS::SQS::Queue':
            RArn = identifier.get('ResourceArn') 
            step0 = RArn.split(':')
            step1 = step0[5]
            response1 = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/SQS',
            MetricName='ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                    'Name': 'QueueName',
                    'Value': step1
                },
            ],
            StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1),
            EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
            Period=60,
            Statistics=[
                'Average',
            ],
            
            Unit='Count'
            )
            datapoints = response1['Datapoints']
            for values in datapoints:
                averages = values['Average']
                soa += averages
               
    return(soa)

result = SumOfAverages(resources, soa, response, cloudwatch)
print(result)


Response:
[{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 8, 6, 34, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Average': 122.0, 'Unit': 'Count'}]
[{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 8, 6, 34, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Average': 101.0, 'Unit': 'Count'}]
[{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 8, 6, 34, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Average': 94.0, 'Unit': 'Count'}]


[{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 8, 6, 34, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Average': 122.0, 'Unit': 'Count'}]
[{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 8, 6, 34, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Average': 101.0, 'Unit': 'Count'}]
[]
```

Comment: Check `NextToken` in the response to your `list_group_resources` request.

Comment: @jarmod there is no attribute as "NextToken" in the response to list_group_resources

Comment: OK was just checking in case results were paginated. Do all of the SQS queues show up in the AWS console for resource groups?

Comment: @jarmod yes all are them are displayed in the console and most of the time in boto3 too. The problem is sometimes some of the queues are returning null sets.

Comment: Now I have uploaded the responses to the same code. You can see that in the second response one of the queues returned a null set.